# HQL query with join columns

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I have 3 entities

**Marche**

```
public class Marche implements  Serializable,Cloneable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,generator="marche" )

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade= CascadeType.ALL )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SUBSELECT) 
    private List<Marchetraveau> marchetraveau;
}
```

**Marchetraveau**

```
public class Marchetraveau implements  Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,generator="marchetraveau" )
    @Column(name="idmarchetraveau")
    private int idmarchetraveau;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idtraveau")
    private Traveaux traveaux ;
}
```

**Traveaux**

```
public class Traveaux implements  Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,generator="traveau" )
    @Column(name="idtraveau")
    private int idtraveau;
    @Column(name="article")
    private String article;
    @Column(name="designation")
    private String designation;
}
```

and I want to select Marchetraveau that have Traveaux.idtraveau equal to a parameter so I wrote the following query

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select mar.marchetraveau  from Marche mar inner join mar.marchetraveau as t where t.traveaux.idtraveau = :idtrav ");

        q.setParameter("idtrav", idtrav);
```

but the problem here that the result is all the marchetraveau from all Marche , it means hibernate is ignoring `where t.traveaux.idtraveau = :idtrav`  what should I do?

**edit1**

PS: I can't select directly from Marchetraveau because the table marchetraveau contains lines that I don't need, by selecting Marchetraveau from Marche I guarantee that I select just the Marchetraveau that are included in a Marche

Comment: I don't understand, why do you try to make a select from **Marche**? Try this one: `em.createQuery("from Marchetraveau where traveaux.idtraveau = :idtrav ")`

Comment: @PyanovEugen please take a look at the modified question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference from Marcheveau to Marche:

```
public class Marchetraveau implements  Serializable {    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idmarche", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Marche marche;
}
```

Usually it's better to have the @ManyToOne side in charge of the association, so this would be even better:

```
public class Marchetraveau implements  Serializable {    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idmarche")
    private Marche marche;
}

public class Marche implements  Serializable,Cloneable {

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="marche")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SUBSELECT)    
    private List<Marchetraveau> marchetraveau;

}
```

So the @OneToMany side is mappedBy now and it's the @ManyToOne FK side to control this bidirectional association.

With this bidirectional association in place we can join the Marche in your query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery(
"select m " +
"from Marchetraveau m " +
"inner join m.marche " +
"inner join m.traveaux t " +
"where t.idtraveau = :idtrav"
);
q.setParameter("idtrav", idtrav);
q.getResultList();
```

### Update

For bi-directional associations you have to set both sides whenever you add/remove a child:

```
public addChild(Marchetraveau marchetraveau) {
    marche.getMarchetraveau().add(marchetraveau);
    marchetraveau.setMarche(marche);
}

public removeChild(Marchetraveau marchetraveau) {
    marche.getMarchetraveau().remove(marchetraveau);
    marchetraveau.setMarche(null);
}
```

Comment: Thank u for response but i have some problems, first problem @ManyToOne doesn't have insertable and updatable properites so i modified to @JoinColumn(name="idmarche",insertable=false, updatable=false), second problem , after this modification  Marche doesn't contain no more Marchetravaux  stored befored the modification ...

Comment: Check my updated answer. You probably didn't set both sides of the association.